# Running a background task against database objects in Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, razor-pages

I have task that is currently called in the `OnGet` method in a razor page, which is a reasonable enough solution, but it might be better to run it, if possible, in the background autonomously

The task pulls a list of all the jobs and their attached invoices and performs a few service checks.
The primary function of the method is to check for overdue invoices, and if necessary update the job status to overdue, post a late fee, and send out an email to the customer.

But while I have everything running I'm also doing just a little bit of error checking and cleanup of the job objects, making sure their status code matches what it should be for example.

Right now I have the data class injected into the page via interface with DI and called in the `OnGet` method of a certain page -so how it functions is whenever the user accesses his business account, this method will run and perform all the necessary actions. That works, but has its drawbacks. I don't really need to run it every time the page loads, for example. That's unnecessary use of system resources to be running that check on what could potentially be a large stack of data. That also has a negative impact on page response time. It really only needs to run no more than once per day. And on the other side of that, if the app user accesses his account infrequently, that means notifications aren't sent out when they need to be. The way the dates for the fees are calculated is entirely agnostic of the time when the function is called so that's not a problem.

So the question is, in this case what is the best way to run this as a scheduled task that is called once per day? Or is this even the best solution for this case?

Here is the method in question as it works currently. I'll go ahead and post it here as is, because I don't think there's really anything special to it or anything being exposed that will compromise the security of my data. Ill include it here so you get a better picture of what I'm trying to do, why I want to move it outside of a page model, and maybe even advise as to whether what I want to do is even worth it or a better solution than what I am doing currently.

```
public async Task CheckIfPastDueAsync(Master master)
{
    List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();
    //We need to be able to handle if a business doesn't have any customers. If so, let's get out of here, we don't need to do anything else.
    if (master.Customers == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (var customer in master.Customers)
    {
        if (customer.Jobs == null) { continue; }
        jobs.AddRange(customer.Jobs);
    }

    //we also don't need to do anything if there are no jobs to check.
    if (jobs.Count == 0) { return; }

    foreach (var job in jobs)
    {
        //this will track whether the job object needs to be updated or not. No need to run the updateasync method if no changes have been posted to the job.
        int changes = 0;
        //disgregard any jobs that don't yet have invoices
        if (job.Invoices == null) { continue; }
        //we don't need to do anything with jobs that are fully paid, so let's move on.
        if (job.Status == 6) { continue; }
        if (job.Status is 1 or 2 or 3)
        {
            //if we've got this far, the job has an invoice and the status doesn't reflect that. Let's fix that.
            job.Status = 4;
            changes++;
        }
        foreach (var invoice in job.Invoices)
        {
            //check to see if a job should be marked as paid but for some reason isn't
            if (invoice.Paid == invoice.Total)
            {
                job.Status = 6;
                changes++;
                //we don't need to do anything more with this invoice so let's move on. Since a job is only going to have 1 invoice by design, this will also move on to the next job.
                continue;
            }
            //This task will test to see if for some reason a Job has been wrongly marked as over due. This might happen with database manipulation leading to possible errors, for example. Fix it if that's the case.
            if (invoice.DueDate > DateTime.Now && invoice.Job.Status == 5)
            {
                invoice.Job.Status = 4;
            }
            //this task will run in the case that a job has not already been marked as late. Has the ability to post multiple fees to the appropriate dates in case the job has not been checked in some time.
            if (DateTime.Now >= invoice.DueDate && job.Status != 6 && job.Status != 5)
            {
                job.Status = 5;
                changes++;
                var late = DateTime.Now - invoice.DueDate;
                //we are checking how late the invoice is, then calculating how many late fees need to be posted based on this and the period decided by the business policies.
                var penalties = Convert.ToInt32(late.TotalDays / master.PayPeriod);
                int newpenalties = penalties;
                int existing = 0;
                //this check should never pass in this environment, but we'll leave it hear just in case something goes wrong.
                if (invoice.Fees != null)
                {
                    existing = invoice.Fees.Count;
                    newpenalties -= existing;
                }
                //this check should ALWAYS pass in this environment, but against we'll leave it here just in case.
                //in theory, if we've passed the first condition to get into this task at all, there will be at least 1 late fee to post.
                if (newpenalties > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < newpenalties; i++)
                    {
                        var fee = new Fee()
                        {
                            Description = "Late Fee",
                            Date = invoice.DueDate.AddDays((i+1) * master.PayPeriod + existing * master.PayPeriod),
                            //Right now we just have a placeholder for fee percent, later we'll update this to a variable assigned via business policies, so attached to the Master object.
                            Amount = Math.Round(invoice.Total * 0.025m, 2),
                            InvoiceId = invoice.Id
                        };
                        await _feeService.CreateAsync(fee);
                        invoice.Total += fee.Amount;
                        await _invoiceService.UpdateAsync(invoice);
                    }
                    await EmailAsync(invoice);
                }
                //continue to the next invoice because there's no reason to run the next check at this point.
                continue;
            }
            //this check is for jobs that are already marked as late but accumulate additional late fees. There are certain tasks that don't need to be run in this case, like updating the job object.
            if (job.Status == 5)
            {
                var late = DateTime.Now - invoice.DueDate;
                var penalties = Convert.ToInt32(late.TotalDays / master.PayPeriod);
                int newpenalties = penalties;
                int existing = 0;
                //in this environment, we should have at least 1 fee posted to the invoice already so this check should always pass.
                if (invoice.Fees != null)
                {
                    //the 'existing' variable is used so that we can pass it to the date calculation without throwing an exception in case invoice.Fees is null
                    existing = invoice.Fees.Count;
                    newpenalties -= existing;
                }
                //in this environment, we might pass the initial check, but wind up with no new fees to post.
                if (newpenalties > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < newpenalties; i++)
                    {
                        var fee = new Fee()
                        {
                            Description = "Late Fee",
                            Date = invoice.DueDate.AddDays((i+1) * master.PayPeriod + existing * master.PayPeriod),
                            Amount = Math.Round(invoice.Total * 0.025m, 2),
                            InvoiceId = invoice.Id
                        };
                        await _feeService.CreateAsync(fee);
                        invoice.Total += fee.Amount;
                        await _invoiceService.UpdateAsync(invoice);
                    }
                    await EmailAsync(invoice);
                }
            }
        }
        if (changes > 0)
        {
            await _jobService.UpdateAsync(job);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now` <-- You should be using UTC, not the local computer time.

Comment: yes. Good catch. 
Though eventually I do plan to adjust all my time calls to be reliant on the business's local time zone

Comment: ...to be reliant on the business's local time zone" - no, don't do that: you should always use only UTC (internally)  - of course the end-user-visible displayed date+time can be adjusted to their zone but within databases, files, etc - everything should be UTC.

Comment: But will DateTime.Now not return SERVER time, and not client computer time?

Comment: Avoid that question entirely by using `DateTime.UtcNow` and avoid `DateTime.Now`. Also, what do you mean by "server" or "client" computer time? (It shouldn't matter:  UTC is the same everywhere, that's the whole point of using it)

Comment: It will be irrelevant in the final code, but -UTC time is not what I want in many of the cases where I am pulling the datetime element. I want the local time for the business. The discrepancy of several hours could potentially result in things being posted incorrectly, notifications being sent out incorrectly, etc. 
Basically, the datetime element I am comparing to IS NOT going to be stored as UTC Time. It might not matter so much in this specific case but it will elsewhere. 
It's still true that DateTime.Now isn't what I want either.

Comment: As to client vs. server, my understanding is that it doesn't matter where in the world the user of the App is when this code is executed. The code is hosted on a physical server somewhere in the world. That server just so happens to be in the Eastern US, and the DateTime.Now calls always return back a time coordinate to Eastern time zone. 
So if the user is the next state over in Central time, the calls should always still be in Eastern time, since they are happening server side and not client side.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca

Comment: Either way I do plan eventually to alter the code to make the time elements dependent on the time zone where the business using the service is physically located. That will require a fair amount of work to implement it, however.

Comment: @Dai please do not misunderstand this to be me arguing and telling you that you are wrong. I'm trying to relate what I am hoping to accomplish and why. SO in this method for example, if I rely solely on UTC time, the customer could be assessed a late penalty of potentially  thousands of dollars when he still has time to pay. This is obviously a problem.
The fix to that is simple, but to me it seems like unnecessary addition of code. Please help me to understand exactly why the use of a time-zone dependent time value would cause issues in this use case?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how UTC works or how to use UTC in database applications: this statement makes no sense: _"if I rely solely on UTC time, the customer could be assessed a late penalty of potentially thousands of dollars when he still has time to pay."_ - UTC time is **universal**, that's the point. Do you not understand the concept of normalization?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to perform such a task. Depending on your access to the server and its operating system, you could put this is in a console app and schedule it with a task scheduler to run once a day for all accounts, or you could use a third party scheduling package such as [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). Or you could use [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services).

Bear in mind that the application needs to be running if you go for Quartz.NET, Hangfire or an IHostedService implementation. This may be problematic if your app is, for example, an intranet app that is only used between say 8.00am and 5.00pm weekdays. It could well idle when not in use (depending on your web server configuration) in which case none of these options will do their job at 2.00am. In that scenario, a scheduled task would be a better option.

Comment: That's more or less what i was encountering, and why i had for now just built the call into a page model. That is, for to the application idling and the high likelihood that it will idle in production as well.

Comment: Hence why I asked, is this even the right approach? (moving it to run as a background task) I knew I wanted to change how it's called, but wasn't convinced what I was looking to do was right. Thanks for confirming it is not.
For now the app is hosted on Azure, I don't know where it will be hosted in the long term. So not entirely sure what my options are with Azure, and obviously if I need to run a console app to run the tests I'll need to choose a server that will let me do that.

Comment: I have never used Azure, but a quick search tells me that they offer scheduled tasks as a service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview

Comment: There are also "ping" services that make requests to your app on a frequency set by you to keep it alive (easily found if you search). The downside of these services is that your app never recycles which might result in larger than necessary resource usage - potentially important in an Azure environment.

Comment: yes I do not want to prevent my app from idling in Azure.
I will definitely pursue creating a scheduled task to do the job. Thanks again.